# Amazon Beanstalk ebcli.objects.exceptions.ServiceError: Failed to deploy application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
Creating application version archive "app-8dfd-161111_001943".

Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-97f2b48f] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...b:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-97f2b48f'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 150, in main
>       app.run()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
>       return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
>       return func()
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
>       return func()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 57, in default
>       self.do_command()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/controllers/deploy.py", line 94, in do_command
>       staged=self.staged, timeout=self.timeout, source=self.source)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/operations/deployops.py", line 45, in deploy
>       can_abort=True)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 91, in wait_for_success_events
>       if _is_success_string(event.message):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 264, in _is_success_string
>       raise ServiceError(message)
>
> ebcli.objects.exceptions.ServiceError: Failed to deploy application.

This error appears when I deploy my application to eb (eb deploy). How do I deploy this successfully?

Comment: Use a _block quote_ for each longish quote/error message (precede contents with `> `).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application failed to deploy onto the EC2 instance. You should be able to get a detailed log of what went wrong by downloading the logs and checking them.

You can get the logs with the EB CLI like so:

`eb logs --all`

The log file that will have the deployment logs will be the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` which you can find here after running the above command:

`/PROJECT-ROOT/.elasticbeanstalk/logs/latest/i-xxxxxxx/var/log/eb-activity.log`

The error logs of why your instance failed to delete should be in this log file.